# Why type is not inferred when leaving away generics operator

Tags: java, generics

I read that since Java 7, creating Collections with specifying the type on the right side like in the first statement is bad style because the compiler can infer the type from the left side.

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

My question is when initializing the list like this, the compiler does not find the type and I get an unchecked type warning:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The compiler doesn't *infer* the type, because you're instantiating a *raw* `ArrayList`. But it's smart enough to warn you that there might be problems when working with this (raw) object.

It's worth mentioning the reason behind this warning. Due to the [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), the parametric information (`<Integer>`) about the `List` will be completely gone at Runtime, when the variable would hold elements of type `Object`. Consider this snippet:

```
List rawList = new ArrayList(); //raw list
rawList.add(new String("hello"));
rawList.add(new Double(12.3d));
List<Integer> intList = rawList; // warning!
```

This snippet will compile, but will generate few warnings. Having a raw list (`rawList`), you can add any non-primitive type to the list, including `String`, `Double`, etc. But when assigning this collection to a list, which is specified to hold **only** integers, then this is a problem. At Runtime you'll get a `ClassCastException` when trying to fetch some element from the `intList`, which is supposed to be an `Integer`, but in reality is a `String` or something else.

Long story short - **do not** mix raw types with Generics!

In your case, the compiler **would possibly** have inferred the type, if you have used the diamond:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); //¯\_(ツ)_/¯
                                  ↑↑
```

Answer (score 12):

Because you have forgotten the angle brackets(called diamond operator).

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is syntactically equivalent to

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

but different to

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList();
```

In the 3rd you are saying that the right side is a raw type meaning the ArrayList can hold every object (not only Integer). Generics are just compile time and are compiled into save type casts.

Comment: Why does this give the compiler more information than List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList() since on the left side the generic information is availabe

Comment: Because both are semantically different. Omitting the type in the diamond is just syntactic suggar.

Answer (score 8):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html:

> Note that to take advantage of automatic type inference during generic
>   class instantiation, you must specify the diamond. [...] **The `HashMap()` constructor refers to the `HashMap` raw type**, not
>   the `Map<String, List<String>>` type.

Answer (score 2):

You can use diamond operator to infer type from declaration as specified in JLS [(§15.9)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9),.

> A class instance creation expression specifies a class to be instantiated, possibly followed by type arguments (§4.5.1) or a diamond ("<>") if the class being instantiated is generic (§8.1.2), followed by (a possibly empty) list of actual value arguments to the constructor.

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```